# Why do I get "command not found" when running my Expect script?

Tags: tcl, expect

I have been playing with Expect/TCL today and I was hoping someone can tell me why the script below fails with:

```
: command not found  
./expect3: line 3: send: command not found
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

send " we are going to open up a file for reading, ok? \n"
expect "ok"

set fileopen [open "/home/aaron/text.txt" "r"]

set a [read $fileopen]
send "i am expecting to see a string from the file here $fileopen"

close $fileopen
```

Both the send and close commands fail, yet other scripts I had written with a spawn command seem to work fine?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Next time, just clean it up. Please don't leave it for others if you feel that strongly about it.

Comment: How will one learn if I go cleaning up their messes?

Comment: I have a saying, "when other people stop being dumb, I will learn to spell better." I have a nurological condition that affects my working memory and causes me to make mistakes. Why is it that for me to have a go at some one dumber than me it is called bulling, but it fine for people to assume the mistakes I make are because I am lazy?  An IQ in the top 2% of the population and I get judged on my spelling... go figure!

Comment: No one's judging you on your spelling. Well... *I'm* not judging you; I can't speak for *him*...

Comment: On the internet, no one knows you're a dog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

The main problem is that you aren't separating your commands properly. Commands in TCL must be separated by newlines or semi-colons.

#### Solution

In general, you should only have one Expect or TCL command per line, unless you have a properly-formed compound statement. For example, this revised snippet will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

send "We are going to open up a file for reading, ok?\n"
expect "ok"
```

because the send and expect commands are separated by newlines.

#### See Also

http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/Tcl.html

Comment: Perfect, I have just found out you can used notepad ++ with a plug in edit files directly through SFTP. woks great when working on linux scripts from a windows machine. Only thing is is you create a new file with in notepad++ it gives it the windows EOL formatting! Thank you for pointing out the issues, i think it might have been a while before I thought of that one. :)

Comment: @Devil Tcl's pretty happy about CR-NL handling, adapting to whatever is in the file, but Unix _isn't_. That first `#!` line has to have the right terminator (or you can do `expect ./yourscript.exp` instead of `./yourscript.exp` to override the exec-magic searching).